# Sitecore 9.1.1 Database CPU crashing ocassionally - XDB query in suspect

Tags: xdb, sql-database, performance

I am having trouble debugging why my CPU utilization occasionally reaches 100%!

The query I see which is taking time is

```
...
RETURN (
        SELECT TOP 1
            [xdb_refdata].[DefinitionMonikers].[ID]
        FROM
            [xdb_refdata].[DefinitionMonikers]
        INNER JOIN
            [xdb_refdata].[Definitions]
        ON
            [xdb_refdata].[Definitions].[ID] = [xdb_refdata].[DefinitionMonikers].[ID]
        WHERE
            [xdb_refdata].[DefinitionMonikers].[MonikerHash] = @hash AND
            [xdb_refdata].[DefinitionMonikers].[Moniker] = @Moniker AND
            [xdb_refdata].[Definitions].[TypeID] = @TypeID
    )
...
```

Can someone tell me if the above query is the one causing the issue or if it only the victim?

Also, how can I identify where the issue lies?

If I recycle the CM and XDB services the performance is back to normal.

Comment: Have you applied this patch? https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/595419

Comment: Thanks Chris !! That seems to have fixed it ! Not having DB issues anymore

Comment: @ChrisAuer I don't want to take your points, but your answer is the correct answer and should be converted to an answer, not a comment so you can get all of those juicy points.

Comment: Thanks @PeteNavarra!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to apply this patch. Sitecore optimized SQL to prevent this issue.

https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0595419